# ffplay - specify a input pixel format from UVC cam (via V4L2)

Tags: ffmpeg, v4l2, mplayer, uvc

I develop a UVC device that can stream the video but its output format is RGB565, and UVC is not supported RGB.
So, I declare my output is YUV422 (also 16 bit per pixel), now I can see my image but its color is incorrect (of course..).

Is it possible to use any tool (ffplay/vlc/mplayer/etc..) to force the input pixel format without to reference v4l2 device capability?
Thanks everyone.

Comment: What is your workflow? UVC device > V4L2 > ffplay?

Comment: Maybe, yes. Actually I did not have any precondition about this. The only goal is to play UVC video on Linux, and force the pixel format become RGB565. (Because it be set to YUV422 on my UVC descriptor, V4L2 will auto-parser it.)